# tkinter multi threading auto start

Tags: python, tkinter

So in my tkinter app I need to check input on button but when I start the program with this code it starts the function (without me clicking the button) and I have no idea why it does that is.

```
submit = tk.Button(app,text='Submit details',bg='black',fg='white',
                   command=threading.Thread(target=get_input_info).start()).grid(row=4)
```

Comment: You are also assigning the value `None` to `submit` because that's what the `grid()` method *always* returns.

Comment: `tkinter` isn't meant to be called from different threads. So please only call `tkinter` functions from the thread where you created the `Tk()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove Parenthesis -

```
command=threading.Thread(target=get_input_info).start
```

Or use, lambda (useful when you need to pass args) -

```
command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=get_input_info).start()
```

Comment: If using lambda, it should be `lambda:threading.Thread(target=get_input_info).start()`.

Comment: Sorry. Good Pointed!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the pair of parantheis from the end of the `command` argument.

eg:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading


def hehe():
    print("some stuff")

win=Tk()
submit = Button(text="something", command=threading.Thread(target=hehe).start).pack()
win.mainloop()
```